# How to know if the last elements are deleted in a map?

Tags: c++

I have two maps (for sake of simplicity let's focus only on keys). I want to compare and tell the differences.

Target Map:
1
3
4
6
7
8
9

Reference Map:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10
11

Using a while loop, I'm able to find differences easily. From the reference, I can tell 9 is inserted, 2, 5, 10, 11 are deleted. But the order/index at which the elements are deleted in the reference are important to me.

Deleting 10 and 11 are okay as they are at the end and doesn't disrupt order. While 2 and 5 are in middle somewhere and deleting them will disrupt the order.

How do I flag only 2 and 5 elements but not 10 and 11? I'm coding in c++.

Since I'm iterating element by element (it.begin() to it.end()), when I reach element 10 I can't tell it's the end. Because at that time I don't know that element 11 will be deleted or not.

EDIT:
More context: I have an enum of values stored on a map. During serialization/deserialization I want all of them in the order. If some changes occur in the middle (insertion/deletion) then the enum for the items below the changed item will be affected. If the last element is changed (inserted/deleted) then there is less or no effect for the rest of the elements. So far, I have this and my goal is to ignore the changes at the end of the map.

```
 while (it1 != a.end() && it2 != b.end()) {
        if (it1->first < it2->first) {
            cout << "insertions: " << it1->first << endl;
            if (it1->second < max_b) {
                cout << "order disrupted: " << it1->first << endl;
            }
            ++it1;
            continue;
        }
        if (it2->first < it1->first) {
            //TODO: Check if deleted at the end. If yes, then no order disruption.  
            ++it2;
            continue;
        }
        ++it1;
        ++it2;
    }
```

Comment: you can try [reverse iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/rbegin/) run from end to start insted of start to end

Comment: Instead of describing your code, why don't you actually show what you've attempted. It'll be easier to help that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can tell 9 is inserted, 2, 5, 10, 11 are deleted

Do this first. Now, iterate the deleted results starting from the back, and compare to the reference map starting from the back. If the elements match, then the deleted element is last and can be removed from the results if that is what you try to achieve. Move the iterators forwards, and keep comparing until the elements differ or you reach the end of the range.

Comment: I used a reverse_iterator and basically did a diff. That solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a combination of `std::set_difference` and `std::upper_bound` will help?

I am not fully sure about your requirements. If my answer does not fit, then please comment and I will delete the answer.

Please see the following example code using `std::vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,10,11 };
    std::vector<int> v2{ 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    std::vector<int> diff;


    std::set_difference(v1.begin(), std::upper_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.back()),
                        v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));

    for (auto i : v1) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << "\nminus\t";
    for (auto i : v2) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << "\nis:\t";
    for (auto i : diff) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: There is a bug with this code. You're always setting the last value v2.back() as the limit. So, when I change the v2, it doesn't work.
11, 12 and 13 are still the end and shouldn't be flagged. But they are reported in the result.

1 2 3 4 33 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13
minus   1 3 4 6 7 8 9 44 4234
is:     2 33 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13

Answer (score 0):

They way I do it is:

1) Iterate over map A, and for each item in map A, see if that item exists in map B.  If not, that item was deleted.

2) Iterate over map B, and for each item in map B, see if that item exists in map A.  If not, that item was inserted.

Note that this technique will work on any data-structure with efficient item-lookups, because it doesn't depend on any particular iteration-order.  In particular, it will work on `std::unordered_map`'s as well.